# Why does std::condition_variable.wait() not lock again if exception occurs?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, standards, condition-variable

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait:

> Atomically releases lock, blocks the current executing thread, and
>   adds it to the list of threads waiting on *this. The thread will be
>   unblocked when notify_all() or notify_one() is executed. It may also
>   be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason,
>   lock is reacquired and wait exits. **If this function exits via
>   exception, lock is also reacquired. (until C++14)**

I cannot understand why the highlighted statement is removed since C++14.

Does it mean:

**Since C++14, if this function exits via exception, lock will not be reacquired?**

If yes:

**What's the rationale behind?**

Comment: C++14 specifies that the function calls `std::terminate()` instead of throwing, when it fails to meet its postconditions. The reason is, pretty much the only way it can fail is if it is unable to re-acquire the lock in the first place. So the requirement in C++11 was kind of chicken-and-egg.

Comment: The specific wording change was introduced in [DR2135](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2135). Consult it for more detailed rationale.